# I am trying to scrape Feature Image using scrapy in python but it's giving 'None' in fact I have attempted to 3 to 4 methods to Scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape Feature Image using scrapy in python but it's giving 'None' in fact I have attempted 3 to 4 methods to Scrape, but they are not working. can anyone please help me why any of my codes not giving the source link of the image, thanks in advance.

Here is the Code.

```
class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cruisefever"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = input("Enter the article url: ")
        
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        Feature_Image = response.xpath('//*[@id="td_uid_2_634abd2257025"]/div/div[1]/div/div[8]/div/p[1]/img/@data-src').extract()[0]
        #Feature_Image = response.xpath('//*[@id="td_uid_2_634abd2257025"]/div/div[1]/div/div[8]/div/p[1]/img/@data-img-url').extract()[0]
        #Feature_Image = response.xpath('//*[@id="td_uid_2_634abd2257025"]/div/div[1]/div/div[8]/div/p[1]/img/@src').extract()[0]
        #Feature_Image = [i.strip() for i in response.css('img[class*="alignnone size-full wp-image-39164 entered lazyloaded"] ::attr(src)').getall()][0]

        yield{
            'Feature_Image': Feature_Image,
        }
```

Here is the website link https://cruisefever.net/carnival-cruise-lines-oldest-ship-sailing-final-cruise/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scrape the featured image using this `xpath`,

```
class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cruisefever"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = input("Enter the article url: ")
        
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        image_tag = response.xpath('//div[@id="tdb-autoload-article"]/div/div/article/div/div/div/div/div/div//img')[1]
        Feature_Image = image_tag.attrib['src']

        yield{
            'Feature_Image': Feature_Image,
        }
```

Comment: How did you create or get this xpath, I want to know to solve this issue for any site in future.

Comment: @InfoRewind There are no such sites that I know. I use inspect mode in chrome and `ctrl+f` and apply the `xpath` there. Then I will do the refinements on it.
Hope this code worked for you.

Comment: Also, use the shell feature in the scrapy. Which will provide you with interactive options.